# Taking a screenshot of a vnc session within a python script

Tags: python, screenshot, vnc

I need to be able to take a screenshot (of a vnc session, if putting this in the title and tags wasn't clear enough) within a python script under OSX. The remote system is already running a vnc server which I am using for other purposes, and will eventually cover the full range of common desktop operating systems, so I would prefer to keep using vnc as opposed to some other solution.

*I do not have a vnc window open on my test server, as it runs headless*. I have tried using [vncdotool](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool/), but I'd prefer not to have to shell out, and trying to mimic the control flow causes problems because Twisted does not allow you to restart the reactor, but if you leave it running it blocks the main thread, and there seem to be problems trying to run the reactor in a separate Thread or Process...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon what tangentStorm suggested, using selenium to take a screenshot. Try doing this. Open up `src/Selenium2Library/keywords/_screenshot.py` and look at lines 24-30.

```
     background leaking when the page layout is somehow broken.
     """
     path, link = self._get_screenshot_paths(filename)
     self._current_browser().save_screenshot(path)

     # Image is shown on its own row and thus prev row is closed on purpose
     self._html('</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><a href="%s">'
```

Delete the line `self._current_browser().save_screenshot(path)` and add directly in its place

```
if hasattr(self._current_browser(), 'get_screenshot_as_file'):
    self._current_browser().get_screenshot_as_file(path)
else:
    self._current_browser().save_screenshot(path)
```

So in all it should look like:

```
    background leaking when the page layout is somehow broken.
    """
    path, link = self._get_screenshot_paths(filename)
if hasattr(self._current_browser(), 'get_screenshot_as_file'):
    self._current_browser().get_screenshot_as_file(path)
else:
    self._current_browser().save_screenshot(path)
    # Image is shown on its own row and thus prev row is closed on purpose
    self._html('</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><a href="%s">'
```

Then try using selenium to take the screenshot.

Reference: [Fix](https://github.com/korda/robotframework-selenium2library/commit/0c52e076c335f6804899fee9ea7d1b2a7904773f)

Comment: I'm going to give you the bounty because this solves my problem - I'll hold off on accepting it though in case someone can give me an answer that is closer to what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments, it seems what you actually want to do is take screenshots of remote web browsers running your flash game.

... And you're using selenium to test those remote web browsers.

... Why don't you just have selenium take the screenshots for you?

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html

Comment: This only makes a best effort - I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'save_screenshot'`

Comment: Okay, well best of luck. Maybe I'm just misreading things, but you seem really antagonistic to everyone who's responded here, and I don't really want to continue this. Sorry. You know more about this than I do at this point, anyway, and I'm sure you noticed Google turns up a bunch of results for that error message. I bet you'll figure it out. Cheers. :)

Comment: sorry if I've come across as antagonistic - it's probably my frustration coming through that it's something that feels like it should be simple, yet there does not seem to be a way of doing it the way I meant to, which would have made my architecture a lot more simple. For this I apologise. The guidelines for downvoting a post however are that an answer is not helpful, for instance if it does not answer the question asked, so if this is what you saw as antagonistic, it is simply the system of this site.

Comment: Yeah, it drives me nuts too when things that should be easy aren't. No worries about the downvote. I was just surprised because I misunderstood your original question and thought I _was_ being helpful. The rewrite is much clearer. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library that does this in python for OSX.

However, there are at least three other ways to get the screenshot:

1. Use the [java.awt.Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class from jython. (Except twisted probably won't run on jython.)
2. Port Apple's [ScreenSnapshot](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html) example to [Cython](http://www.cython.org/) and compile it into a python module. (Of course you can do the same thing in C, but Cython makes it much more fun.)
3. If you can move your server to win32, or just run win32 on your mac via parallels, then you can use the python imaging library's [ImageGrab](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm) module.

However, I think shelling out to the OS is still the easiest answer. Instead of trying to get it all to run in a single process, just have two processes running: your main twisted process, and some other server that uses threads or whatever.

Then just pass messages back and forth when you want to take a screenshot. You can do this with a simple socket connection (just write another handler to in your twisted server, and have the screenshot server connect as a client)...

If it were me, I'd probably use an AMQP server like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) to handle the message-passing, but that may be overkill for what you're doing.

Comment: This takes a screenshot of the local system - please re-read the question and consider either deleting or revising your answer

Comment: I think in common usage, a VNC session is a vnc client window running on your local machine. I'm saying take a picture of that window. If instead you're making a direct connection using the VNC protocol... Then how on earth could you not already know what's on the screen? That's what the protocol does. Please rewrite the question instead of downvoting everybody's answer. :)

Comment: @tangenstorm perhaps the downvotes were harsh, but I thought I'd made my question fairly clear, and the question these answered was not the question I had asked.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code, you might be able to use `deferToThread` to run the call to `screencapture` and return the filepath or a `pil.Image` instance (or whatever you need).

Using the example at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/gendefer.html#auto5 it might look something like...

```
from subprocess import call
import tempfile
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
import Image ## pip install pil


## Blocking code that takes the screenshot and saves to file
def take_screenshot():
    tmp_file_path = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.png')
    # os.system('screencapture %s' % tmp_file_path)
    retcode = call(['screencapture', tmp_file_path])
    if retcode < 0:
        img = Image.open(tmp_file_path)
        return img
    else:
        return None


## Callback fired by the deferToThread
def do_something_with_screenshot(img):
    print img.filename, img.format, img.size, img.mode
    reactor.stop() ## just here for this example


def run():
    # get our Deferred which will be called with the largeFibonnaciNumber result
    d = threads.deferToThread(take_screenshot)
    # add our callback to print it out
    d.addCallback(do_something_with_screenshot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: This takes a screenshot of the local system, however I shall try your way of deferring twisted to another thread, to see if this holds merit

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want a screenshot of the remote side of a VNC session. Is this session run graphically? i.e. can you simply take a local screenshot of the VNC window? If not, can you ssh into the remote machine and call `screencapture`? At a push, you might look at remote applescript (remote apple events)

Comment: While it would be possible to remote over and take a screenshot, any such solution would have to work across all common desktop operating systems and across all common browsers. The script requesting this screenshot however will always be running on an OSX system, and a vnc session on the remote machine is a requirement of the tests that my script is running. The vnc session is not rendered locally, but is used by a third-party commercial tool, that I do not have the source code for. Surely it should not be so difficult to connect to a vnc session, take a snapshot, and then disconnect?

Comment: I'm guessing that using twisted is leading me up a blind alley, as this must be run in the main thread? Unfortunately the framework that I am using to execute my script must also be run in the main thread...

Comment: I'm not sure the issue here is thread-related, but rather getting access to a vnc session. Is the vnc connection initiated by your python script? If so, how does the third-party tool interact with it?

Comment: Unfortunately the third party tool is closed source - it interacts directly with the vnc session. I found vncdotool, which I have added a link for in my question, which will take a screenshot when called from the command line, but I wish to be able to call just exactly what I need to take the screenshot, as opposed to shelling out from my script, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @BiggAl Depending on the framework your using, Twisted might already have a reactor that integrates with it: QT, GTK, eventlet, select, poll.  If so you can run the reactor without blocking your main loop.

Comment: @Marc do you have a link to anywhere I could find out more about this?

Comment: @BiggAl Not sure which framework you are using so here are some general links. 
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html
http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonAndTwisted,
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/QTReactor, 
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.html,

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convince the robotframework or Selenium to send a `CaptureScreen` Sensetalk command to Eggplant Drive.

The [Taking a Screenshot](http://www.testplant.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=2219) post in the TestPlant forums mentions this command.

Comment: This is one workaround, but is inferior to the one I am using as it requires that I then get the image from the eggplant drive machine to the test run machine